# How to properly pass environment variables for local development in Backstage.io

Tags: environment-variables, backstage

I have setup my `app-config.yaml` to use environment variable substitution (EVS) like bellow:

```
auth:
  environment: development
  providers:
    gitlab:
      development:
        clientId: ${AUTH_GITLAB_CLIENT_ID}
        clientSecret: ${AUTH_GITLAB_CLIENT_SECRET}
```

And this works fine when deployed though my CI/CD pipeline. but for local development I have not found a good way to inject environment variables.

I do have an `app-config.local.yaml` but I would like to avoid having essentially having two copies of `app-config.yaml, one with hardcoded values and the other with the EVS.

What is the best way to load environment variables so that app-config.yaml can read them.

This is a very similar question to [How to edit environment variables in Backstage.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77104564/how-to-edit-environment-variables-in-backstage-io) But the question asker never gave an example of how they are actually adding it into their `app-config.local.yaml` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: I used a [`.env.yarn` file](https://yarnpkg.com/features/scripting)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77950324/6010125